# EV3 .py to .rbf?

Tags: ev3, python

So, I need to send an `rbf` file from my computer to e-mail for a tournament.  I'm currently using python with the ev3 microPython setup and vscode. The question is, where or how can I get the `rbf` file from a `.py` code?

Comment: I don't think an .rbf file is ever generated, the microPython interprets and executes the .py file directly. .rbf files were executable files generated by the EV3 software, i.e. either the graphic programming language in the old version (with blocks you needed to draw) or the scratch based new software. I think you should contact the tournament organizers and ask if a .py file is acceptable...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve, you should convert your comment to an answer. :-)

Comment: I did so but wasn't sure it was an answer, could always be that some enthousiast had written a Python to .rbf compiler, although I think it unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an .rbf file is ever generated, the microPython engine installed on the flash disk interprets and executes the .py file directly. .rbf files were executable files generated by the EV3 software, i.e. either the graphic programming language in the old version (with blocks you needed to draw) or the scratch based new software. I think you should contact the tournament organizers and ask if a .py file is acceptable...